# When I connect to mysql, show this problem in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

Please help me solve this problem

[image: see image here Please]

Answer (score 0):

Well, handle the exception, either right there with a `try { } catch` block, or somewhere else in your program.

In the latter case you have to add a `throws` clause to the method declaration.